# rounding django input field makes it dissapear

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a decimal field in my form.

The input displays values like:  `60.00`

I want it to display:  `60`

I have tried:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ form.amount|floatformat }}
```

I have also tried changing my form field to an integer:

```
class AmountInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    amount = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('amount',)
```

This causes the field to disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a DecimalField at all if you just want to display whole numbers? Why not use an IntegerField?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I need decimal fields for precision calculations in the backend.  This number will be divided and manipulated. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That didn't answer the question. If you want to display decimals, use an integer field on the form; you can still store the data in a decimal field on the model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried creating an integer version of the field (above) and it still shows decimal places.  Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: @DanielRoseman did you see my update above?  Was this what you were suggesting in the form?  It still renders a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I see that you are applying floatformat to an input element and not to a valid numeric value. As a consequence, it fails to show and thus Django prefers not to show anything at all.

You could try this workaround then:

First of all, please try printing your form this way:

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

If you look at the source code, you could see that, for example, the input for the field called **name** is displayed this way:

```
<input id="id_name" name="name" maxlength="25">
```

As a consequence, you can emulate this behaviour doing the following in your django template:

```
<input id="id_{{form.amount.label}}" name="{{form.amount.label}}" maxlength="25" value={{form.amount.value|floatformat:0}}>
```

Overall,the secret is to apply floatfomat to **form.amount.value** instead of **form.amount**.

Hope it works for you!